# how to find if a string exists in oracle column

Tags: oracle

i have a table that store mutiple values in column i need to find if the value exists then return entire row

```
Example : 963963963;35793579;741741
```

Query am using

```
select * from table where column like (%963%);
```

which return all the rows that have the value starts or ends with 963

i need only one row that match with 963

Answer (score 1):

It is generally bad table design to store semicolon separated data this way.  If you *must* continue with your current design, you may use the following query to find an exact match for `963`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ';' || col || ';' LIKE '%;963;%';
```